# Dictionary get method not working with a received request data

Tags: python, ajax, flask

What I'm trying to do is that from a **textbox** send a value to the server. Then search this value in a dictionary and place the result in a **div**. For example if my dict is `d = {'a': "1", 'b': "2", 'c': "3"}` and I get "a" from the textbox it should write 2 inside the div. But instead the value isn't found and returns the default result. What is the problem? it might be something stupid but I couldn't find it. Here's my code:

### VIEW

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

d = {'a': "1", 'b': "2", 'c': "3"}


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/demo_test", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def demo():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.data
        print "dict: {}".format(d)  # I can access the dict from here
        print "res {}".format(d.get("b", "meh"))  #get() is working with a string. Returns "2"
        print "request data: {} type: {}".format(data, type(data))  # I'm receiving data without problems
        ndata = d.get(data, "meh")  # For example if I receive "b" the result is "meh". It should be "2" 
        print "ndata: {} type: {}".format(ndata, type(ndata))
        return ndata

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type=text/javascript
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="selector" name="selector">
    </form>
    <div id="div1"></div>  

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#selector').change(function () {
      var value = $('#selector').val()
      $.ajax({
              type : "POST",
              url : "{{ url_for('demo') }}",
              data: JSON.stringify(value),
              contentType: 'text/plain',
              success: function(result) {
                  $('#div1').html(result)
              }
          });
   });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what it all print out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a *JSON* string; this includes quotes. As such you are trying to look up `'"b"'`, not `'b'`:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps('b')
'"b"'
```

Best actually tell the server you are posting JSON and load the data as such on the server side:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "{{ url_for('demo') }}",
    data: JSON.stringify({'key': value}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
        $('#div1').html(result)
    }
});
```

and on the server side:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.get_json()
    ndata = d.get(data['key'], "meh")
    return ndata
```

Comment: Thanks I thought that **JSON.stringify** was making *value* a **string**. I just changed to `data: value`